# How to retrieve nested array element from MongoDB using C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Now I have one entity and a nested array

```
public class Author {
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Book> Books { get; set; }
}

public class Book {
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public String ISBN { get; set; }
}
```

and pre defined mongodb collections like

```
var authors = mongodbDatabase.getCollection<Author>("Authors");
```

Here's the problem, is there a way to directly retrieve one or some "Book" from MongoDB with specified "Author" (not to retrieve the entire "Author" then LINQ the books I want)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Projection as follows:

```
var filter = Builders<Author>.Filter.Eq("Books.ISBN", "987654321");
var projection = Builders<Author>.Projection.Include("Books.$").Exclude("_id");
var book = context.AuthorCollection.Find(filter).Project(projection).SingleOrDefault();
```

This will return a `BsonDocument` which has the book.

Comment: Thanks for reply. From the code, is it means the  _Project()_ method with _Projection.Include()_  tells MongoDB driver to return only the fields specified?

Comment: Yes, correct. You can see more examples here: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/driver/definitions/#projections

Answer (score 2):

A different way without any static string

```
var filter = Builders<Author>.Filter.ElemMatch(p=>p.Books,t=>t.ISBN == "987654321");
var projection = Builders<Author>.Projection.Include(p=>p.Books[-1]);
var author = context.AuthorCollection.Find(filter).Project<Author>(projection).SingleOrDefault();
```

Please note that the data you need will return as an author and you can reach it from `author.Books`